# Examine C pointers with GDB

Tags: c, pointers, gdb

I am readying a book currently, and I am learning to examine pointers in C with GDB. In the book, when you examine the pointer, the output is as follow:

```
(gdb) x/xw pointer
0xbffff7e0: 0x6c6c6548
(gdb) x/s pointer
0xbffff7e0: "Hello, world!\n"
(gdb)
```

But when I do it myself I get the following output:

```
(gdb) x/xw pointer
0x7ffff7de59a0 <_dl_fini>:  0xe5894855
(gdb) x/s pointer
0x7ffff7de59a0 <_dl_fini>:  "UH\211\345AWAVAUATSH\203\354(L\213%\250\177!"
```

My question is: Why do I get such a different output. 
I know I am doing something wrong, but, what is it?

Thanks everyone.

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char str[20];
    char *pointer;
    char *pointer2;

    strcpy(str, "Hello, world!\n");
    pointer=str;
    printf(pointer);

    pointer2=pointer+2;
    printf(pointer2);
    strcpy(pointer2, "y you guuuys!\n");
    printf(pointer);
}
```

Comment: When using old books, add the `-m32` option to all your cc and gcc commands to increase the chances that your compiled code will match that in the book.

Comment: Remember my name is "SuperNoob"... and I really mean that.

Comment: I tried your code and put a breakpoint at line 12 and I got the same result as your book. Cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Edit your question to include ALL your commands to gdb.

Answer (score -1):

What I suspect your "error" is, is that "x/s pointer" returns the "string" pointed by your pointer (remember : a string terminates with \0). 
However your pointer in this case is not a string, which is why you get that weird "string"